# Inherit custom exception class from both boost::exception and std::runtime_error

Tags: c++, boost

I would like to introduce a hierarchy of my custom exception classes, derived both from boost::exception and std::runtime_error so that `what()` returns something meaningful.

So far I had no luck:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <boost/exception/all.hpp>

typedef boost::error_info<struct tag_foo_info, unsigned long> foo_info;

struct foo_error : virtual boost::exception, virtual std::runtime_error
{
  explicit foo_error(const char *const what)
    : std::runtime_error(what)
  { }
};

static void foo()
{
  BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(foo_error("foo error") << foo_info(100500));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  try
  {
    foo();
  }
  catch (const std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << boost::diagnostic_information(e);
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

just keeps complaining that there are `no appropriate default constructor available` for `std::runtime_error`.

The closest I can get is to throw an actual `std::runtime_error` using

```
BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(boost::enable_error_info(std::runtime_error("foo error")) << foo_info(100500)))
```

but that's not really what I want. Basically, I want an exception class being `catch`able by `catch (const std::exception& e)`, `catch (const std::runtime_error& e)`, `catch (const boost::exception& e)` and `catch (const foo_error& e)`. Is that possible? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need public inheritance

```
struct Exception : public boost::exception, public std::runtime_error
{
    Exception()
    :   std::runtime_error("Hello World")
    {}
};

int main()
{
    try {
        try {
            throw Exception();
        }
        catch(const std::runtime_error&) {
            std::cout << "std::runtime_error" << std::endl;
            throw;
        }
    }
    catch(const boost::exception&) {
        std::cout << "boost::exceptionr" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Your code will work if you replace the two virtual:

```
Throw in function void foo()
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<foo_error>
std::exception::what: foo error
[tag_foo_info*] = 100500
```

The boost exception library has a class deriving from your exception:

```
// Curiously recurring template pattern (exception.hpp:419:20)
class clone_impl: public Exception, public clone_base;
```

Due to virtual inheritance the most derived class is responsible to initialize the base classes (clone_impl does not)

Comment: Could you please explain _why_ and _how_ does this work? My brain hurts.

Comment: I mean, you just replaced `virtual` with `public`. What is the difference? Why does it work now? What are the consequences? I'm struggling to understand.

Comment: The boost exception library has a class deriving from your exception.

Answer (score -1):

std::runtime_error already inherits from std::exception. So you only need inherit std::runtime_error and you'll get both.

UPDATE:
I meant inheriting *only* std::runtime_error. What if you try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

struct foo_error : public std::runtime_error
{
    explicit foo_error(const char *const what)
        : std::runtime_error(what)
    { }
};

static void foo()
{
    throw foo_error("foo error");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    try
    {
        foo();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << boost::diagnostic_information(e);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

left out the boost stuff for simplicity.

Comment: I'm in fact inhereting from ``std::runtime_error`` on the example posted, but it won't compile. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This answer seems to confuse `std::exception` and `boost::exception`. They're not the same things. Inheriting `std::runtime_error` does *not* automatically inherit from `boost::exception`.